# PHP Ternary: Inline if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, inline

While there is nothing wrong with the following code it's bothering me because I know it could be a simple one line.

```
if (Auth::user()->id != 1){
    echo User::where('owner', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', 2)->count();
}else {
    echo User::where('status', 2)->count();
}
```

I am just having problems constructing the statement. If someone could advise please I have tried several variations of:

```
echo User::(Auth::user()->id != 1 ? where('owner', Auth::user()->id)->)where('status', 2)->count();
```

Comment: This is useful. I was working on something using this too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I like ternary for echo (personally), but if you really want to:

```
echo Auth::user()->id != 1
    ? User::where('owner', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', 2)->count()
    : User::where('status', 2)->count();
```

Comment: it was more for the fact i knew there was another way, not so certain that it was a better way but one of those things i had to see through! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hey each to their own, totally :)